# UIScrollView scroll strangely when UISearchBar begin editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a view with a search bar and a scroll view.
My views layout like below.

- UIView

  - UISearchBar
  - UIScrollView

    - UITableView(the first page)
    - UITableView(the second page)

The scroll view scroll strangely by steps below.

1. Make the scroll view scroll to second page
2. Touch the search bar
3. While showing search display controller,the scroll view scroll to first page strangely.

How to make the scroll view stay in second page?

Oh,no!!I hope I had enough reputation to post image.

Comment: Hello, can you post your code? Where is the second uitableview located?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex Thank u for your reply. I figure it out this morning.The cause of this error is because I made a wrong constraint.